# Redirection and hostname

Tags: redirection

Is it possible, on a linux local machine, to force all requests on the 443 port toward an hostname (defined in /etc/hosts) to use another port?

Eg.: If my browser tries to get https://host.domain.org , it will be host.domain.org:666 that will be contacted.

I know some browser extensions exist but I'm searching for a system level solution.

Must I use iptables?

UPDATE:
This host is a front portal of my entreprise and exposes a dozen of ports, each of them is a redirection on a back HTTPS server.
For instance:

- https://host.domain.org:1001 leads to a zimbra server
- https://host.domain.org:1002 leads to a GLPI server
- etc

Until now, I used to use an extension for chromium (named switcheroo) that redirects an URL according to its pattern. So I wrote a line into my /etc/hosts like this:

```
ip_of_the_portal    zimbra.mydomain.org glpi.mydomain.org
```

And in my extensions, i wrote some rules like this:

```
"https://zimbra.mydomain.org" -> "https://zimbra.mydomain.org:1001"
"https://glpi.mydomain.org" -> "https://glpi.mydomain.org:1002"
```

So, every time a collegue gives me an url for Zimbra, my browser automatically concats ":1001" and all is running just fine.

The problem I encounter is about a tricky webserver (let's say, avaible on port 1002 of the public PAT portal) that gives some HTTP redirections in request responses, and my little extension is unable to cope with it and it bypasses my rules.

Comment: Can I ask why you are tying to do this from the client side? Do you control the server https://host.domain.org? If that's the case you can actually set up a redirect that will take you to the right place.  
  
/etc/hosts is going to be useless to you. It simply tells what dns corresponds with what ip address.

Comment: I don't control the server. It offers multiple services on a dozen of ports (PAT). What I try to achieve is when I want to join https://host.domain.org my system redirects the browser to host.domain.org:666

Comment: Erk, that's going to be tricky then. Operating systems don't like playing around with ports, especially 443 - if someone could write a line in /etc/hosts that would change what port certain sites run on - they could potentially compromise the security of the connection.  
   
Sorry. Perhaps someone will know more then me about this subject.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Why do you want to mess with the ports? Which PCs (client(s), server) are you controlling?

Comment: I'm going to modify my initial post because some infos are missing (I have troubles with the english language ^^)

Comment: iptables is based on IP addresses. This will not work in your case. As Arthur said the server approach would be the best. I do not how to solve that with a client side system wide solution.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, instead of doing something too tricky or impossible, I wrote a chromium extension that changes the "Host" HTTP header of every request.

The problem was that the Apache server reads the "Host" http header to make some decision. As I'm coming from the outside of the entreprise via a PAT, this header is "host:port" and when the Apache sees an unknown port in this field, it sends a 302 to redirect instead of the requested page.

To circumvent this problem, my extension removes the ":port" of the Host HTTP header and the Apache server returns the right page.

Thanks to everyone who read and answer my dumb initial question :).